# neo4j Cypher hierarchical tree build response to JSON

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Can you help me to build cypher query?** i have following graph db structure:

```
(parent:Category)-[:subcategory]->(child:Category)
```

With this graph data i have hierarchical tree with deep level.

I found following code on Stackoverfllow.com and changed for my data:

```
MATCH (root:Category)-[:subcategory]->(parent:Category)-[:subcategory]->(child:Category)
WITH root, {category: parent, children: collect(child)} AS parent_with_children
WHERE NOT(()-[:subcategory]->(root))
RETURN {category: root, children: collect(parent_with_children)}
```

But he is build response only for depth with 3 levels of tree. I need bigger. I'm try to build json response like this example:

```
  [
    category: {
      name: "PC"
      children: {
        category: {
          name: "Parts"
          children: {
            category: {
              name: "CPU"
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        category: {
          name: "Accessories"
          ...
        }
      } 
    }, 
    category: {
      name: "Laptop"
      ...
    }
  ]
```

The Cypher can make recursive calls? I think this will be better.

**Thanks.**

P.S. I know there are similar questions on SO, but they did not help me.

Comment: Yeah, Cypher doesn't really do recursion.  When returning a tree of data your best bet is going with what cybersam suggests below or returning the nodes / relationships as a table and building them in memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Cypher` is not well suited for dumping out graph data in a tree structure when leaves are at arbitrary depths.

However, with neo4j 3.x, you can get close to what you want if you are able to install the [APOC plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) on your server and use the `apoc.convert.toTree` procedure.

First, let's create some sample data:

```
CREATE
  (c1:Category {name: 'PC'}),
    (c1)-[:subcategory]->(c2:Category {name: 'Parts'}),
      (c2)-[:subcategory]->(c3:Category {name: 'CPU'}),
        (c3)-[:subcategory]->(c4:Category {name: 'CacheRAM'}),
    (c1)-[:subcategory]->(c5:Category {name: 'Accessories'}),
      (c5)-[:subcategory]->(c6:Category {name: 'Mouse'}),
      (c5)-[:subcategory]->(c7:Category {name: 'Keyboard'}),
  (c10:Category {name: 'Laptop'}),
    (c10)-[:subcategory]->(c20:Category {name: 'Parts'}),
      (c20)-[:subcategory]->(c30:Category {name: 'CPU'}),
    (c10)-[:subcategory]->(c40:Category {name: 'Accessories'}),
      (c40)-[:subcategory]->(c50:Category {name: 'Stylus'});
```

Then with this query:

```
MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)
WHERE NOT ()-[:subcategory]->(n)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value;
```

... you will get N result rows, where N is the number of root `Category` nodes. Here is a snippet of sample results:

```
{
  ...
      "row": [
        {
          "_id": 150,
          "_type": "Category",
          "name": "PC",
          "subcategory": [
            {
              "_id": 154,
              "_type": "Category",
              "name": "Accessories",
              "subcategory": [
                {
                  "_id": 156,
                  "_type": "Category",
                  "name": "Keyboard"
                },
                {
                  "_id": 155,
                  "_type": "Category",
                  "name": "Mouse"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "_id": 151,
              "_type": "Category",
              "name": "Parts",
              "subcategory": [
                {
                  "_id": 152,
                  "_type": "Category",
                  "name": "CPU",
                  "subcategory": [
                    {
                      "_id": 153,
                      "_type": "Category",
                      "name": "CacheRAM"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
  ...
      "row": [
        {
          "_id": 157,
          "_type": "Category",
          "name": "Laptop",
          "subcategory": [
            {
              "_id": 158,
              "_type": "Category",
              "name": "Parts",
              "subcategory": [
                {
                  "_id": 159,
                  "_type": "Category",
                  "name": "CPU"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "_id": 160,
              "_type": "Category",
              "name": "Accessories",
              "subcategory": [
                {
                  "_id": 161,
                  "_type": "Category",
                  "name": "Stylus"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
  ...
}
```