# Neo4j - Difference between Cypher query in Browser vs with Driver? (WITH COLLECT, apoc, etc)

Tags: javascript, angular, neo4j, cypher

I'm running an identical query in the Neo4j browser and in my JavaScript (Angular) code, but getting two different results. I haven't had any issues with basic queries until now. I imported the neo4j-web driver so can use in Angular:

`import * as neo4j_driver from 'neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js';`

I needed to have hierarchical data, and so I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578114/neo4j-cypher-hierarchical-tree-build-response-to-json)

The following query will work in Neo4j browser
      `MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)
      WHERE NOT (m)-[:subcategory]->()
      WITH COLLECT(p) as ps
      CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
      RETURN value;`

However, when executing the exact same query in my JS code:
    
    `const result = this.session.run(
      'MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)' +
      'WHERE NOT (m)-[:subcategory]->()' +
      'WITH COLLECT(p) as ps' +
      'CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value' +
      'RETURN value;'
    );`

I get the following error in the browser console:

    `Error: Invalid input 'a': expected whitespace, comment, ',', ORDER, SKIP, 
    LIMIT, WHERE, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, 
    REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, 
    column 100 (offset: 99))
    "MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)WHERE NOT (m)-[:subcategory]->()WITH 
    COLLECT(p) as psCALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield valueRETURN value;"
                         ^
    at new n (neo4j-web.min.js:17)
    at t (neo4j-web.min.js:17)
    at l.value (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l._dechunker.onmessage (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.value (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.value [as _state] (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.value (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.u._ch.onmessage (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at WebSocket._ws.onmessage (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at WebSocket.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onmessage] (zone.js:1032)`

At first I thought it might be a problem with Apoc given where the caret is pointed; however, I checked other Apoc functions and they work fine, and then I just removed the Apoc line altogether and instead ran :
       
    `const result = this.session.run(
      'MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)' +
      'WHERE NOT (m)-[:subcategory]->()' +
      'WITH COLLECT(p) as ps' +
      'RETURN ps;'
    );`

Which also results in an error if running from code but works in Neo4j browser. Error from console:

`Error: Invalid input 'p': expected whitespace, comment, ',', ORDER, SKIP, LIMIT, WHERE, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 102 (offset: 101))
"MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)WHERE NOT (m)-[:subcategory]->()WITH COLLECT(p) as psRETURN ps;"
         ^
    at new n (neo4j-web.min.js:17)
    at t (neo4j-web.min.js:17)
    at l.value (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l._dechunker.onmessage (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.value (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.value [as _state] (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.value (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at l.u._ch.onmessage (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at WebSocket._ws.onmessage (neo4j-web.min.js:18)
    at WebSocket.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onmessage] (zone.js:1032)`

Any ideas what is going on here? Been beating my head against the desk all day and nothing I try seems to work. I'm new to Neo4j and may have made some beginner mistake, but I'd really like to know why identical queries have different behaviours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add whitespace (like a space or newline) between clauses, otherwise the query string is not always parsed the way you intended.

Try this (notice the extra space at the ends of the first 4 strings):

```
const result = this.session.run(
  'MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m) ' +
  'WHERE NOT (m)-[:subcategory]->() ' +
  'WITH COLLECT(p) as ps ' +
  'CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value ' +
  'RETURN value;'
);
```

#### Details

Your original query resulted in the following query string:

```
MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)WHERE NOT (m)-[:subcategory]->()WITH COLLECT(p) as psCALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield valueRETURN value;
```

The Cypher parser was tripped up by `psCALL` and `valueRETURN`.

Comment: well, that was easy, thanks cybersam! (and thank you for your example I'm using :) )