# Neo4j / Cypher - How to retrieve categories with AND without subcategories

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578114/neo4j-cypher-hierarchical-tree-build-response-to-json), the following query will return all categories along with their subcategories:

```
MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*]->(m)
WHERE NOT ()-[:subcategory]->(n)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value;
```

How can the query be modified to **also** get categories without subcategories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor tweak should do it:

```
MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:subcategory*0..]->(m)
WHERE NOT ()-[:subcategory]->(n)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

The `*0..` pattern includes 0-length paths (i.e., paths with no subcategories).