# Receive JSON data from Neo4j to Spring Boot API

Tags: spring, api, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to send data from Neo4J to Spring boot and I want to receive a JSON like this:

```
{
  "name": "Alex Statham",
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Jason Statham",
      "people": [
        {
          "name": "Lyna Statham"
        },
        {
          "name": "John Statham"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Will Statham",
      "people": [
        {
          "name": "Michael Statham"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I try many query and this one maybe the best query which returns a correct family tree for all cases, but it only return nodes with no relationship so I can't put that data to the Library I use:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {maBN:3})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(p1, {
    sequence: '>Person,FCHILD,>Person,FCHILD,>Person',
    maxLevel: 6
}) YIELD node
RETURN node, p1
```

Here is that Library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tree-graph

What should I do? I don't know too much about Cypher and Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

You could use apoc.convert.toTree which takes a list of paths and creates a structure like yours.

Comment: Can you give me an example or a link?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578114/neo4j-cypher-hierarchical-tree-build-response-to-json/38579683#38579683